# Form control selection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

How to change order of control selection in C# Window form. I wanted to change where text box appears in the form, but now when I use Tab key it skips that text box an later goes to it. I've worked with WPF and I would just change control position in XAML, but I can't do it in Win form.

Comment: Set the Tab Index property and you are done

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that adds a button and sets its **TabIndex** property

```
// Create a button and add it to the form.
Button button1 = new Button();

// Anchor the button to the bottom right corner of the form
button1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right);

// Assign a background image.
button1.BackgroundImage = imageList1.Images[0];

// Specify the layout style of the background image. Tile is the default.
button1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;

// Make the button the same size as the image.
button1.Size = button1.BackgroundImage.Size;

// Set the button's TabIndex and TabStop properties.
button1.TabIndex = 1;
button1.TabStop = true;

// Add a delegate to handle the Click event.
button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

// Add the button to the form. 
this.Controls.Add(button1);
```

Alternatively you can also take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (To set from Design)

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, It's TabIndex property. Thanks